# R plm fixed effect model where the index and fixed effects variables are not the same

Tags: r, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, plm

I used the `plm()` function for a 2-way fixed effect model with `zip_code` and `month` (yy-mm) fixed effects. The data table used for the model is panel data with `id` and `date` (yyyy-mm-dd) as the panel indexes.

The model looks like this:

```
plm(DV ~ IV + zip_code + month, data = panel_data, effect = "twoways", index = c("id", "date"), model = "within")
```

However, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28359491/r-plm-time-fixed-effect-model) that the effect argument takes the index arguments as fixed effects variables, i.e., first index: "group" (id), second index: "time" (month) or both: "twoways" (id, month).

How can I specify `zip_code` and `month` fixed effects that are not indexes?

Additional question: Do I need to format `month` and `date` variables for the `plm()` function? For example, `month` as `yearmon` and `date` as `Date` or would `factor()` work as well?

Comment: Welcome. Isn't `id` and `date` your zip code and month identifiers, respectively?

Comment: Thank you! Not necessarily - an `id` can have different `zip codes` on different `dates`. The data for one `id` looks like this: 
`id - date (365 days) - month (12 months)- zip code (card >=1) - DV - IV`
If it would help I could reduce the zip code to a cardinality = 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/562373/94889

Answer (score 0):

> How can I specify `zip_code` and `month` fixed effects that are not indexes?

It's permissible to include *additional* fixed effects in this context. According to the comments, the `id`'s can move around over time, so if I know your `id`, then I don't necessarily know your zip code. I suppose if you also want to estimate zip code fixed effects, then simply include indicator variables for all the different postal zones. In R, it's as simple as including the zip code variable, as is, assuming it's a character or factor variable. To be safe, use `as.factor(zip_code)` on the right-hand side like you would any other variable.

```
# `as.factor(zip_code)` denotes zip code fixed effects

plm(DV ~ IV + as.factor(zip_code), data = panel_data, effect = "twoways", index = c("id", "date"), model = "within")
```

> Do I need to format month and date variables for the `plm` function? For example, month as `yearmon` and date as `Date` or would factor work as well?

It depends.

Including month fixed effects is akin to including a dummy variable for each month. If you have a "month-year" panel with *more than one* year, then you should concatenate month and year. In short, a repeating month variable (e.g., 1 – 12) is not appropriate. A true "time" fixed effect would distinguish between, say, January in 2015 and January in 2018. Thus, creating a variable like the one you're proposing will work just fine (e.g., `"2020-Jan"`, `"2020-Feb"`, `"2020-Mar"`, etc.). But if you really only have 12 months, then this is not necessary since the month variable uniquely identifies each time period.

Note, however, that the month fixed effects are redundant with the day fixed effects. If the date variable is a running "day-of-the-year" variable, as I suspect it is, then those day-specific effects are collinear with the month fixed effects. The function should warn you about this. I would consider modeling "month" in a different way. Maybe you want to capture some cyclical pattern in the raw data that repeats annually but is the same year-over-year. Or maybe that pattern varies by geography. If these concerns are of substantive interest, then maybe you don't have to omit month from the model.

The short answer to your question is, yes. We can most certainly estimate fixed effects that are not indexes. That being said, in settings with multiple (high-dimensional) fixed effects, the [`fixest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fixest/fixest.pdf) package has the edge over `plm` in terms of speed.